# Python unable to refresh the execution of script

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import time
import xlsxwriter
import re
import os

urlpage = 'https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Racing/LocalResults.aspx?RaceDate=2019/07/14&Racecourse=ST&RaceNo=1'

# Setup selenium 
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'geckodriver path')
# get web page
driver.get(urlpage)
time.sleep(10)

bs_obj = BSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

# Scrape table content
table = bs_obj.find('table', {"f_tac table_bd draggable"})
rows = table.find_all('tr')
table_content = []

for row in rows[1:]:
    cell_row = []
    for cell in row.find_all('td'):
        cell_row.append(cell.text.replace(" ", "").replace("\n\n", " ").replace("\n", ""))
    table_content.append(cell_row)

header_content = []
for cell in rows[0].find_all('td'):
    header_content.append(cell.text)

driver.close()

race_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('export path', engine='xlsxwriter')

df = pd.DataFrame(table_content, columns=header_content)
df.to_excel(race_writer, sheet_name='game1')
```

Hi All, I am trying to scrape the racing result from HKJC. When I was executing the code above, either one of the errors below happened:

1. No excel file is created
2. Df is not written to the excel file < an empty excel file is created
3. Say if I successfully scrape the result of game 1, I then amend the script to continue to scrape that of game 2, but it still gives me the result of game 1.

Appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your script to the one below. The approach followed is to click through each of the **relevant** "Sha Tin" buttons (see `range(1, len(shatin)-1)`) and collect the race table data. Race tables are added to a list called "races". Finally, write each of the race tables to individual sheets in Excel (note you no longer need `BeautifulSoup`).

**Add these to your list of imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

**Then:**

```
urlpage = 'https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Racing/LocalResults.aspx?RaceDate=2019/07/14&Racecourse=ST&RaceNo=1'

# Setup selenium 
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'geckodriver path')
# get web page
driver.get(urlpage)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//table[@class='f_fs12 f_fr js_racecard']")))
shatin=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='f_fs12 f_fr js_racecard']/tbody/tr/td")

races=[]
for i in range(1, len(shatin)-1):
    shatin = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='f_fs12 f_fr js_racecard']/tbody/tr/td")
    #time.sleep(3)
    #WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='performance']")))
    shatin[i].click()
    table = pd.read_html(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='performance']").get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
    races.append(table)

with pd.ExcelWriter('races.xlsx') as writer:
    for i,race in enumerate(races):
        race.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'game{i+1}', index=False)
    writer.save()

driver.quit()
```

**Output:**
[image]